# Limit of a multivariable function raised to a power

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I got this limit in one of my math exams, but I got stuck because I couldn't decide which term was of a greater significance, $(x^2+y^2)$ or $e^{(-x-y)}$.

Maybe I'm not even on the right path.

How to solve this limit?

$$\lim_{(,y)→(\infty,\infty)}(x^2+y^2)\cdot e^{(-x-y)}$$

Comment: Consider the expression $~x^2e^{-x},~$ when (for example) $~x = 10^6.~$  The easiest way to evaluate the expression is by taking the natural log of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using polar coordinates, we may rewrite the limit as $$\displaystyle \lim_{r\to\infty} r^2\cdot e^{-r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))}$$ As $x,y\geq 0$, $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$, so $\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\geq 1$, and $$0\leq r^2\cdot e^{-r(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta))}\leq r^2\cdot e^{-r}\to 0,$$ so the limit is $0$.

Comment: How can you be moving along the line $~x = -y,~$ when $~x~$ and $~y~$ are both going to $~+\infty~?$

Comment: I didn't understand $\infty$ as $+\infty$, I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=x+y \to\infty$ then we reduce to

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{ e^{(x+y)}}\le \frac{(x+y)^2}{ e^{(x+y)}}=\frac{t^2}{e^t}$$

which is  awell known strandard limit.